# Display loaded UI Image in Container with native size

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to display UI logo images in their aspect ratio but in proper size that fit within its container. Already all logo images as per aspect ratio but few are too big or small compare to requirements.

At present this kind of thing happening:

[image]

Here is the code that I am using:

```
private void ShowGamePlayLogoViewed ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < DataCollection.companyDetailsList.Count; i++) {
        Company company = DataCollection.companyDetailsList [i];
        if (company.ViewedCounter > 0) {
            GameObject companyItemObj = Instantiate (companyItemPref, gridViewContainer) as GameObject;
            CompanyItem companyItem = companyItemObj.GetComponent<CompanyItem> ();
            companyItem.companyId = company.CompanyId;
            companyItem.UpdateCompanyLogo (company.CompanyLogo);
            companyItem.UpdateCompanyName (company.CompanyName);
        }
    }
}
public void UpdateCompanyLogo (Sprite logoSprite)
{
    logoImage.sprite = logoSprite;
    logoImage.SetNativeSize ();
}
```

As you are seeing, logos overlapping the container. I want to display properly them in their respective containers also in aspect ratio too.

Let me clarify one more thing: all logos loaded from web server and they all are dynamic at a time, based on server data it will appear in mobile screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution through Unity Forum and I want to say thanks to @Hosnkobf for reply.

Here is the exact reply that worked for me properly:

adjust the image game object inside unity so that it has the height you are looking for. also adjust the anchors so that it scales with different resolutions properly.
Add an "AspectRatioFitter" component to the object. Make it "Height controls width".
Instead of logoImage.SetNativeSize (); do the following:

```
float aspectRatio = logoSprite.rect.width / logoSprite.rect.height;
var fitter = logoImage.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.AspectRatioFitter>();
fitter.aspectRatio = aspectRatio;
```

I hope this become useful to other members :)